# How does your navigation software update the recommended route when the initial position estimate was wrong?

Tags: algorithm, gps, graph-theory

You've just input a destination address into your navigation software on your phone. It calculates what it believes to be the route that will take the shortest amount of time.

As you are driving you experience some GPS drift and the navigation software thinks you've taken the offramp on the freeway.

I am wondering from an algorithm perspective, how does the navigation software know to correct itself when it estimates a more accurate location a second later? This question may seem simple, but I am looking for a pretty specific answer.

I am guessing that the application has a graph stored in memory of several nodes which depict different road locations (this is also so that it knows how to plot a line in the right direction). When it guesses you exited at the offramp, it realizes your estimated distance from the node it thinks you went to is too far to be accurate, so it backtracks on the graph and goes the other way and finds the correct node. Is this correct? Or is it much simpler? Does it do a DFS back until it finds the node closest to your current position?

Comment: Please don't mix up "GPS" and "navigation software". "GPS" is the *Global Positioning System*, which is a billion dollar satellite system, which your GPS receiver uses to *only* give you *your* location, to some degree of accuracy. The navigation software is what finds the route from your location to your destination. This was extremely hard to understand until I realized you're mixing up these terms! I will correct your question (and really, if you're into route finding, you *should* be more exact with your terminology. You're not at an electronics store "selling a GPS").

Comment: I'm taking back your <strike>estimates<strike> –> *receive* edit. Your GPS receiver does *not* receive a position. It estimates it from the satellite position (more general: from the satellite signals) it receives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's very many different navigation systems out there, and they use different algorithms, so I doubt there can be a general answer, but:

What is typically the "textbook" approach to fast navigation is a two-sided slightly modified Dijkstra. In other words, you start from your beginning, and mark all directly connected nodes with the time it'll take you to get there and the node you came from.

Then you repeat that with the nodes connected to these nodes. Rinse, repeat. If you encounter a node that has been seen before, you compare the time your "new" path takes to get there with the one already marked there. Only the shorter one survives.

You do that, alternatingly, from both your start and your destination. (You can be a bit smart – for example, you'll rarely go 50km on back roads in the wrong direction). At some point, both trees "meet". You can basically make a graph cut among all the nodes that you find can be reached from both ends, and use that path that goes through the node of the shortest distance.

Now, back to your problem: Your navigation system finds you've taken a road it didn't expect you to take. No problem, that node can only be one that is directly connected to the node it though you were at – other nodes are unlikely, unless you can teleport. Now, since Dijkstra, as explained above, has already calculated how long it takes to get to that node, it's just a matter of pivoting the tree. Really, pretty standard tactic if you're doing route planning.

So, you have interesting questions! I recommend that, if you haven't, you read about *Dijkstra's algorithm*.